# Does C have __func__ functionality for names of the arguments of a function?

Tags: c, func

Does the "C" standard support something similar to `__func__` for the function arguments' names?

Comment: You will have to elaborate a bit on this...

Comment: I think he means to ask if C has any macro that expands to the parameters of the function its in, and the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want a quick and dirty solution for this make pre-processor macros like this...

```
#define FUNCTION_HEADER(a) a { const char* __func__ = #a;
#define FUNCTION_FOOTER() }
```

... and use it for your function headers and footers like this (tested with VS 2008):

```
#include <windows.h>

#define FUNCTION_HEADER(a) a { const char* __func__ = #a;
#define FUNCTION_FOOTER() }

FUNCTION_HEADER( int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) )
    MessageBoxA(0, __func__, __func__, MB_OK);
    return 0;
FUNCTION_FOOTER()
```

This should work exactly how you want, but it is ugly.

Comment: Ugly indeed, but does the job :-)

Answer (score 5):

No, the C99 standard has the following:

> 6.10.8 Predefined macro names
>
> The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:

```
__DATE__ 
__FILE__ 
__LINE__ 
__STDC__ 
__STDC_HOSTED__ 
__STDC_MB_MIGHT_NEQ_WC__ 
__STDC_VERSION__ 
__TIME__
```

> The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:

```
__STDC_IEC_559__ 
__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__ 
__STDC_ISO_10646__
```

> 6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers
>
> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>     immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration

```
     static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.63)

gcc adds some [extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Function-Names.html#Function-Names), as I imagine other compilers do.