# Name of a function in C++ or C

Tags: c++, c, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it ever possible to get the current (member) function name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769898/is-it-ever-possible-to-get-the-current-member-function-name-in-c)

If given a function `int func(args)`in C or C++ is there a way to get the name, or even signature, of the function fromwith in the body of `func`

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
void func(void) 
{
    printf("%s", funcinfo.sig);
}
```

and have the output be:

```
"void func(void)"
```

does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: funcinfo.sig what is? a function? a variable?

Comment: In C99 you have the identifier `__func__` with the name of the function ("func" in your example), no way to get function type or parameters.

Comment: For the C part: [Does C have `__func__` functionality for names of the arguments of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905999/does-c-have-func-functionality-for-names-of-the-arguments-of-a-function) has the answer.

Comment: @Xeo you are right, that was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` predefined identifier with gcc:

```
void func(void) 
{
    printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

it will print :

```
void func()
```

with gcc in C++

and

```
func
```

with gcc in C

Note that this identifier is a gcc extension. In Standard C, there is the predefined identifier `__func__` but which prints only the function name (C or C++)

Answer (score 2):

"predefined identifier" `__func__` in C99 and C++11` for function name.